# Python: Removing Rows on Count condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, counter

I have a problem filtering a `pandas` dataframe.

```
city 
NYC 
NYC 
NYC 
NYC 
SYD 
SYD 
SEL 
SEL
...

df.city.value_counts()
```

I would like to **remove rows of cities that has less than 4 count frequency**, which would be SYD and SEL for instance.

What would be the way to do so without manually dropping them city by city?

Comment: what is `dropping them city by city`? maybe you should provide your working code. and what you want.

Comment: I was thinking it might be possible to do so by using df.drop(['SYD']) for example, but not working.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Here you go with filter

```
df.groupby('city').filter(lambda x : len(x)>3)
Out[1743]: 
  city
0  NYC
1  NYC
2  NYC
3  NYC
```

Solution two `transform`

```
sub_df = df[df.groupby('city').city.transform('count')>3].copy() 
# add copy for future warning when you need to modify the sub df
```

Comment: This is a fantastic one liner!  I really should use `groupby` more, at the moment it's still a form of black magic to me.

Comment: Nice one. Unfortunately, `lambda` tends to make me sick :(. Only good in small doses!

Comment: @jpp yep , for the small sample size , I think filter is more clear , but only for small sample size

Comment: Tested on a 1 million rows dataframe, jpp’s `value_counts` solution is slightly faster than the `filter` one, but the `transform` solution is much faster than both (the latter took less than 1 s on my dataset when the others took 5.7 s and 8.3 s, respectively).

Answer (score 30):

This is one way using `pd.Series.value_counts`.

```
counts = df['city'].value_counts()

res = df[~df['city'].isin(counts[counts < 5].index)]
```

`counts` is a `pd.Series` object. `counts < 5` returns a Boolean series. We filter the counts series by the Boolean `counts < 5` series (that's what the square brackets achieve). We then take the index of the resultant series to find the cities with < 5 counts. `~` is the negation operator.

Remember a series is a mapping between index and value. The index of a series does not necessarily contain unique values, but this is guaranteed with the output of `value_counts`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! now I got to look into the meaning of '~'

Comment: @DevinLee, that just means elementwise "negate" / "negative" in vectorised functions.

Comment: i don't undertand this part `counts[counts < 5].index`. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Snow, `counts` is a `pd.Series` object. `counts < 5` returns a Boolean series. We filter the `counts` series by the Boolean `counts < 5` series (that's what the square brackets achieve). We then take the index of the resultant series to find the cities with < 5 counts. Remember a series is a mapping between index and value. The index does not necessarily contain unique values, but with `value_counts` this is guaranteed.

Answer (score 9):

I think you're looking for `value_counts()`

```
# Import the great and powerful pandas
import pandas as pd

# Create some example data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'city': ['NYC', 'NYC', 'SYD', 'NYC', 'SEL', 'NYC', 'NYC']
})

# Get the count of each value
value_counts = df['city'].value_counts()

# Select the values where the count is less than 3 (or 5 if you like)
to_remove = value_counts[value_counts <= 3].index

# Keep rows where the city column is not in to_remove
df = df[~df.city.isin(to_remove)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution :

```
threshold=3
df['Count'] = df.groupby('City')['City'].transform(pd.Series.value_counts)
df=df[df['Count']>=threshold]
df.drop(['Count'], axis = 1, inplace = True)
print(df)

  City
0  NYC
1  NYC
2  NYC
3  NYC
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution is much slower than the others.