# Delete rows based on unique number of elements in a column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Given a data frame with two columns `A` and `B`:

```
df = 

A      B
cat    3
cat    4
cat    2
bird   1
bird   3
bird   2
bird   5
bird   3
```

I want to delete rows if the number of unique elements in column `A` is less `3`
len of `cat` is - 3 (delete)
len of `bird` is - 5 (keep)

desired output:

```
df = 

A      B
bird   1
bird   3
bird   2
bird   5
bird   3
```

Comment: This is a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49735683/11301900.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [filter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html):

```
result = df.groupby('A').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 3)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
      A  B
3  bird  1
4  bird  3
5  bird  2
6  bird  5
7  bird  3
```

As an alternative you could use [value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
# find the count by each value of A
counts = df.A.value_counts().to_frame()

# keep those with count above 3
keep = counts[counts.A > 3].index

# filter
result = df[df.A.isin(keep)]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

**This question is a duplicate of [Python: Removing Rows on Count condition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49735683/11301900)**

---

I'm sure there is a better way, I just haven't quite found it yet. I will keep searching.

```py
import pandas as pd

raw_str = \
'''
A      B
cat    3
cat    4
cat    2
bird   1
bird   3
bird   2
bird   5
bird   3'''

df_1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(raw_str), delim_whitespace=True, header=0, dtype={'A': str, 'B': int})


val_counts = df_1['A'].value_counts()

df_1 = df_1[(val_counts[df_1['A']] > 3).reset_index(drop=True)]
```