# count the number of each name and drop names that are repeated less than 2 times

Tags: python, pandas, count, unique

in this dataset

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'name':["a","c","d","b","a","b","c","a","c","d","b","n",
                         "m""b","b","c","a","c","d","b","a","b","b","b","c",
                         "a","c","d","b","a","b","b","b","c","a","c","d","b","a","b","b","b","c"]})
```

I want to count the number of each name and drop names that are repeated less than 2 times.

Comment: Here is a possible solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49735683/python-removing-rows-on-count-condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is using filters:

```
data.groupby('name').filter(lambda x : len(x)>1)
```

Comment: You probably mean: data.groupby('name').filter(lambda x : len(x)>1)

Comment: Thanks @BaruchG. You are right! I will edit it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) and [value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html) functions as follows:

```
   only_duplicates = data[data['name'].map(data['name'].value_counts()) > 1]
```