# Python or R - Concat/Appending rows like an inner join

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe

I have n data frames that represent weekly time periods. I'd like to do something like an inner join (based on id and id2), but for appending rows from all n datasets, not additional columns (as they're all identical).

They all look like this

```
DF1:
id   id2    A      B     C     PERIOD
1     50   0.1    0.2    0.3     1
1    100   0.1    0.2    0.3     1
2     2    0.1    0.2    0.3     1

DF2:
id   id2    A      B     C     PERIOD
1     50   0.5    0.7    0.9     2
1    100   0.6    0.8    0.9     2
1    105   0.1    0.2    0.3     2
2     2    0.3    0.4    0.5     2
2     3    0.1    0.2    0.3     2
```

...repeats for `DFn`

I'd like a data frame that looks like this

```
id   id2    A      B     C     PERIOD
1     50   0.1    0.2    0.3     1
1     50   0.5    0.7    0.9     2
...                              n

1    100   0.1    0.2    0.3     1
1    100   0.6    0.8    0.9     2
...                              n

2     2    0.1    0.2    0.3     1
2     2    0.3    0.4    0.5     2
...                              n
```

So it discards all combinations of id, id2 that don't appear in ALL of my n datasets.
Is there a quick way of doing this?

I was thinking of first going over all n data frames, grabbing sets of pairs id, id2, and doing an intersection of all these sets, and then reduce the data frames by `.isin`, and then `pd.concat` on the list of reduced data frames. This seems tedious though.

Comment: As I can do it in tidyverse or pandas, doesn't really matter

Comment: I'd suggest concat all and then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49735683/python-removing-rows-on-count-condition. Use id, id2 for grouping and set count condition to n

Comment: Smart! I forgot I can clean up duplicates to ensure the different n rows come from n dataframes. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```r
Reduce(function(a, b) {
  rbind(
    merge(a, b[,c("id","id2")], by = c("id", "id2")),
    merge(b, a[,c("id","id2")], by = c("id", "id2"))
  )
}, list(DF1, DF2))
#   id id2   A   B   C PERIOD
# 1  1 100 0.1 0.2 0.3      1
# 2  1  50 0.1 0.2 0.3      1
# 3  2   2 0.1 0.2 0.3      1
# 4  1 100 0.6 0.8 0.9      2
# 5  1  50 0.5 0.7 0.9      2
# 6  2   2 0.3 0.4 0.5      2
```

If you don't want to `merge` twice, then you can use:

```r
Reduce(function(a, b) {
  tmp <- merge(a, b, by = c("id", "id2"), all = TRUE)
  tmp <- tmp[complete.cases(tmp),]
  tmpx <- tmp[,c("id", "id2", grep("\\.x$", colnames(tmp), value = TRUE))]
  colnames(tmpx) <- gsub("\\.x$", "", colnames(tmpx))
  tmpy <- tmp[,c("id", "id2", grep("\\.y$", colnames(tmp), value = TRUE))]
  colnames(tmpy) <- gsub("\\.y$", "", colnames(tmpy))
  rbind(tmpx, tmpy)
}, list(DF1, DF2))
#    id id2   A   B   C PERIOD
# 1   1  50 0.1 0.2 0.3      1
# 2   1 100 0.1 0.2 0.3      1
# 4   2   2 0.1 0.2 0.3      1
# 11  1  50 0.5 0.7 0.9      2
# 21  1 100 0.6 0.8 0.9      2
# 41  2   2 0.3 0.4 0.5      2
```

---

Implementing MYousefi's suggested logic, here's a third alternative:

```r
bind_rows(DF1, DF2) %>%
  group_by(id, id2) %>%
  filter(n() == 2L) %>%  # 2 is the number of frames joined
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 6 x 6
#      id   id2     A     B     C PERIOD
#   <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <int>
# 1     1    50   0.1   0.2   0.3      1
# 2     1   100   0.1   0.2   0.3      1
# 3     2     2   0.1   0.2   0.3      1
# 4     1    50   0.5   0.7   0.9      2
# 5     1   100   0.6   0.8   0.9      2
# 6     2     2   0.3   0.4   0.5      2
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `group_split` from `dplyr` package `R`:
You will get a list!

```
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(DF1, DF2) %>% 
  group_split(id, id2)
```

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 x 6
     id   id2     A     B     C PERIOD
  <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <int>
1     1    50   0.1   0.2   0.3      1
2     1    50   0.5   0.7   0.9      2

[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 x 6
     id   id2     A     B     C PERIOD
  <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <int>
1     1   100   0.1   0.2   0.3      1
2     1   100   0.6   0.8   0.9      2

[[3]]
# A tibble: 1 x 6
     id   id2     A     B     C PERIOD
  <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <int>
1     1   105   0.1   0.2   0.3      2

[[4]]
# A tibble: 2 x 6
     id   id2     A     B     C PERIOD
  <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <int>
1     2     2   0.1   0.2   0.3      1
2     2     2   0.3   0.4   0.5      2

[[5]]
# A tibble: 1 x 6
     id   id2     A     B     C PERIOD
  <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <int>
1     2     3   0.1   0.2   0.3      2
```

If you want to get a dataframe: you could do:

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(DF1, DF2) %>% 
  group_split(id, id2) %>% 
  bind_rows()
```

or simply:

```
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(DF1, DF2) %>% 
  arrange(id, id2)
```

```
     id   id2     A     B     C PERIOD
  <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <int>
1     1    50   0.1   0.2   0.3      1
2     1    50   0.5   0.7   0.9      2
3     1   100   0.1   0.2   0.3      1
4     1   100   0.6   0.8   0.9      2
5     1   105   0.1   0.2   0.3      2
6     2     2   0.1   0.2   0.3      1
7     2     2   0.3   0.4   0.5      2
8     2     3   0.1   0.2   0.3      2
```