# Filter out words from a DataFrame column without listing each word individually

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, geopandas

I'm trying to filter out locations from a DataFram column named "user_location", as the df I'm using has things like "global" and "online" and user's locations. The df has over 170,000 rows, and going through even 10% of that to filter out individual words I spot would take forever, is there any way to make this easier? Like something to scrape the column and show what words are used, making them easier to filter out?

I've tried

```py
nltk.download('stopwords')

tweets["user_location"].fillna("Unknown", inplace=True)

stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))

tweets_cleaned = tweets[~tweets["user_location"].str.lower().apply(lambda x: any([word in x.lower() for word in stop_words]))]
```

and

```py
country_names = [country.name for country in pycountry.countries]

tweets_cleaned = tweets[tweets["user_location"].isin(country_names)]
```

NLTK stopwords removed too many rows because of the amount of 2-3 letter words it has in the list, pycountry's country list filters out anything that isn't strictly the country name. e.g. it filters out things like "New York, NY", as it doesn't contain the words "America" or "USA".

All of this is in an ipynb file. Later on in the file I use Nominatim to gather the approximate location data, with lat and lon coord's, from the values in user_location. I also have Country Codes from the naturalearth_lowres geopandas dataset, which I merge into my main dataset later on in the document. However, I want to filter out as many "invalid" locations as I can first, to remove the incorrect values from my final output.

Is there any way to somehow scrape the column of all the common words used within and display them all?

Comment: how would you define "common words"? [unique values](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html?highlight=unique#pandas-series-unique)? [unique values with a minimum number of appearances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49735683/python-removing-rows-on-count-condition)?

Comment: @Shorn like any country names/codes/short versions of country names